# action bar spinner not matching style, dark spinner text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-styles, android-support-library

I am currently using the Action Bar included in the android.support.v7 package to add Action Bar functionality to my app. I ran into an issue while adding a navigation spinner. When the app is run on devices prior to Honecomb, the text in the spinner appears too dark to be easily read and radio buttons appear along side with the text. I am using the Theme.AppCompat theme for devices prior to Honecomb defined in my values/styles.xml which is a dark theme, but somehow the theme is not being correctly applied to the Action Bar spinner.
Here is the code for the initialization of the spinner.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    actionBar.getThemedContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
    android.R.id.text1, stringArrayGoesHere());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, null);
```

I have heard of alternative libraries such as Action Bar Sherlock but I am not interested in using them at the moment.

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem while using customer theme and the solution is to create the 02 xml files for spinner text and spinner dropdown list text seperately. I think you might do the same for your case.

This is for spinner text: (I'm using holo with dark action bar)

actionbar_spinner.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="7dp"
android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium.Inverse"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="italic" />
```

And this is for dropdownlist text:

actionbar_spinner_dropdown.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:height="40dp"    
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />
```

and then you can put these xml in you code, for example:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    actionBar.getThemedContext(),
    R.layout.actionbar_spinner,
    android.R.id.text1, stringArrayGoesHere());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.actionbar_spinner_dropdown);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, null);
```

Hope it helps..